# Shell(zsh) variable to define the breaks ctrl+arrow jumps to

Tags: shell, zsh, keyboard-shortcuts, environment-variables

I could of swore that I once saw a zsh environment variable that allows you to define the *breaks* or *punctuation* that will be used to jump to when using the shell shortcuts `Ctrl+RightArrow` (move forward by word) or `Ctrl+LeftArrow` (move back by word).

To help explain, say that we have the following command:
`dig A +noall +nocmd some.random.long.domain.us @8.8.8.8 +answer^`
I am at the end of the line here, my cursor being represented by `^`.

When pressing the `Ctrl+Left Arrow` shortcut multiple times the cursor jumps to each of the following marks:`^`
`^dig ^A +^noall +^nocmd ^some.random.long.domain.us @^8.8.8.8 +^answer^`

Now cant I define something in my profile that will determine what it expects to be *end* or *beginning* of a word?

For example, I would like for the shortcut to recognize periods as a point it can jump to, like so:
`^dig ^A +^noall +^nocmd ^some.^random.^long.^domain.^us @^8.^8.^8.^8 +^answer^`

Anyone familiar with this var (if it exists) or maybe even perhaps an alternative way to achieve this functionality?

Comment: See `info zsh select-word-style` or `info zsh WORDCHARS`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word delimiters in zsh](//unix.stackexchange.com/q/552190)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Environment* variables name string variables that are accessible by any command run in the environment. Shells do map some of them to their internal variables, `perl` maps them to its `%ENV` associative array, `awk` to its `ENVIRON` associative array and so on.

You generally only set an environment variable for something that is shared between *commands* (note I didn't say *process*), generally those are well know variables that have special meaning for most commands such as `PATH`, `TZ`, `LANG`...

So a variable that is only used to customise the current command, be it a shell or anything else should *not* be an environment variable.

`zsh` does have indeed a special variable that is used to specify what constitutes a *word* with regards to the `backward-word` and `forward-word` widgets bound by default to <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>b</kbd> and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> in `emacs` mode and that some people also bind to <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd>.

That's the `WORDCHARS` variable (inspired from csh's `wordchars` variable).

`info zsh WORDCHARS` tells us:

> `WORDCHARS` <S>
> A list of non-alphanumeric characters considered part of a word by
> the line editor.

That is alnums are always considered as word characters, and `$WORDCHARS` completes that list.

By default, it has:

```
$ print -r -- $WORDCHARS
*?_-.[]~=/&;!#$%^(){}<>
```

You can remove some with:

```
WORDCHARS=${WORDCHARS//[\;\/]}
```

For instance to remove `;` and `/`.

Or add some like your `+` with:

```
WORDCHARS+=+
```

See also `info zsh select-word-style` for an easier way to switch between different word styles for navigation.